# cannot get MySQL stored procedure into php

Tags: php, mysql, prepared-statement

The following SQL works 100% if I run it in phpMyAdmin, however if I try using it in a php prepare statement in a php file, using:

```
$stmt = $mysqli->prepare("...");
$stmt->execute();
$stmt->close();
```

I get an error. I need to know how to wrap this sql into php, because I must use a .php file

```
SELECT @myCommand := concat("SELECT UNIX_TIMESTAMP( TIMESTAMP( CURDATE( ) ,   HalfHourTime ) ), 0, 0, 0, 0 
into OUTFILE 'C:/wamp/www/myApp/services/csv/filename-", DATE_FORMAT(now(),'%Y%m%d-%H%i%s'), '.csv' "' 
FIELDS TERMINATED BY ','  
LINES TERMINATED BY '\n'
FROM timeintervals_halfhours
");
PREPARE stmt FROM @myCommand;
EXECUTE stmt;
```

It's based [on the post by Frank Flynn on October 6 2006 11:05pm](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/select.html) where he said: "If you wish to use OUTFILE or DUMPFILE with a variable for the file name you cannot simply put it in place - MySQL will not resolve the name."

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is mysqli does not support multi-statment execution in single call.
Take a look on http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.multi-query.php

Comment: The error is: I cannot dynamically assign the filename for the OUTFILE (in which I want to have the current time as part of the filename). I tried splitting into two separate queries:

Comment: For example in two queries (doesn't work):
     require_once('connection.php');
     $q1="SELECT  concat( 'C:/wamp/www/myApp/services/csv/', NOW(), '.csv') AS filename";
     $r1=mysqli_query($dbc,$q1);
     $row=mysqli_fetch_array($r1, MYSQLI_ASSOC);//fetch row of 1st query  
     //set variable for 2nd query
     $file = $row["filename"];
    $q="SELECT UNIX_TIMESTAMP( TIMESTAMP( CURDATE( ) , HalfHourTime ) ), 0, 0, 0, 0 
    INTO OUTFILE $file
    FIELDS TERMINATED BY ','  
    LINES TERMINATED BY '\n' 
    FROM timeintervals_halfhours";
    $r = mysqli_query($dbc,$q);